# Qt 5.2 version is not properly installed on Mac

Tags: macos, qt, installation, osx-lion, qt5

I recently tried to upgrade my Qt version to 5.2, so I uninstalled my previous version (using the MaintenanceTool.app), and downloaded and installed the latest version. That completely broke it, though. Whenever I try to build a project, it says:

```
The Qt version is invalid: Qt version is not properly installed, please run make install.
```

And when opening an example project, it says in the General Messages:

```
Error while parsing file /Users/thisuser/Qt/5.2.0/5.2.0/clang_64/examples/gui/analogclock/analogclock.pro. Giving up.
Could not find qmake configuration file default.
Cannot read /usr/local/Qt-5.2.0/mkspecs/macx-clang/qmake.conf: No such file or directory
Could not read qmake configuration file /usr/local/Qt-5.2.0/mkspecs/macx-clang/qmake.conf.
Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: gui core
Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: gui core
```

I checked this path (`/usr/local/Qt-5.2.0/mkspecs/macx-clang/`) and indeed there is no such thing: there isn't even a `/usr/local/Qt-5.2.0` directory. I already uninstalled everything again and then installed it again, but that didn't help at all. Does anyone have any suggestions on what to do?

My OS is OSX Lion.

Comment: Did you install from http://download.qt-project.org/official_releases/qt/5.2/5.2.0/qt-mac-opensource-5.2.0-clang-offline.dmg , or is that some other installer? Is Qt Creator (assuming you're opening the example project in there) configured correctly to use the newly installed Qt?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the one I installed. I don't know if Qt Creator is configured correctly, how do I check that? The version numbers are correct at least.

Comment: Check that the configured Qt version points to the correct QMake, and make sure to build from a new and clean build directory.

Comment: I build it in a clean build directory, and the QMake points to an existing qmake file. But also there it says "Qt version is not properly installed, please run make install."

Comment: @Yellow: have you set the kit up properly?

Comment: @Yellow Have you managed to find out a solution? I'm having the exact same problem. Mac OS X 10.7.5

Comment: Hmm, I did fix it in the end, but quite frankly, I don't know how. I just reinstalled XCode and tried to install Qt again, twice. The first time failed, the second time succeeded. Why is a mystery to me...